# How can I type tilde (~) in the Ubuntu terminal with a Norwegian keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, symbols

I am using Ubuntu terminal and want to type this:

```
sudo -H -u gitosis gitosis-init < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

However I am not able to find tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) on my Norwegian keyboard.

Can anyone tell me how to type it?

Comment: The name of the symbol is "tilde" in case that helps you find references to it.

Answer (score 32):

F6 gave me ~ on my key board.

Comment: F6 is actually outputting something like `^[[17~` (escape-leftbracket-1-7-~).

Comment: F5 worked on my HP pavilion dv6700, not F6

Comment: I don't know why, but after <kbd>F6</kbd> the <kbd>~</kbd> symbol on keyboard back to work again.

Comment: Also on the german keyboard. 

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>¨</kbd> (umlaut, [just below backspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Norwegian)), then (assuming the deadkey variant of the layout) <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: And similarly option + ¨  followed by a space on a mac...

Comment: might also be to the left of backspace

Answer (score 12):

Hold down together:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> - Underlined u should appear.
2. Release keys
3. Enter 7E (Unicode for ~)
4. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>

For the full list of Unicode codes please refer to the following link:

https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character

It may look too much, but it's the global solution for all languages and keyboard layouts ,)

Answer (score 8):

`~` refers to your home directory, so you can always type `$HOME` instead of `~` ... if you can find <kbd>$</kbd> on your keyboard, that is!

Answer (score 4):

Type the combination like **Alt gr** + **(top right char, for me Ü, for you ^)** and after typing hit "space".

**Briefly**: Type the combination and after **hit space**.