# Tilde on Ubuntu virtual machine with QWERTZ keyboard (MAC)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-fusion

I want to do a tilde (~) on my virtual machine Ubuntu Server (14.04.4) but I couldn't do it from now. I have OSX as OS (QWERTZ keyboard). How is it possible to do it ?

I already look at some topic and this one : [How can I type tilde (~) in the Ubuntu terminal with a Norwegian keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/190025/how-can-i-type-tilde-in-the-ubuntu-terminal-with-a-norwegian-keyboard)

but no one of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I used the cmd+maj+é(ö) to get a ~ it's a tilde to put on another letter like "ñ" so you have to enter another thing to make it appear. It works for what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Type right ‘alt’ and the ‘+’ button, that worked for me

Comment: work fine for me too

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on a german QWERTZ keyboard.

Comment: It works on osx but not on the virtual machine but thanks for the response.